# How to make tabs make a server call when pressing them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the simple example shown [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html) in order to create tabs on my page.
In my case the content of these tabs is not some light text but rather heave jsps and I prefer not to load everything at once.
My question is if there is a way to use these tabs as placeholders and only render the content for each tab's jsp using a server call when the user actually presses them?
A simple code example would be very helpful

Comment: There are (were) examples on the jQueryUI site, which appears to have expired. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to your question is [**HERE**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax)

The relevant piece of HTML being:

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PBWfa/1/) if you look in the firebug under the `xhr` tab you will notice an ajax call being made upon clicking each tab

Answer (score 0):

this demo seems to do exactly what you need: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax.html

A click on a tab start an ajax request for the inside content

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this solution is that my jsps are rendered with Spring mvc and therefore bind to a model. I think I need "real" server call/redirect otherwise it won't resolve the models

Answer (score 0):

The example here sounds like it will do what you are after: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax-history.html

Just replace ajax1.html with your page.

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this solution is that my jsps are rendered with Spring mvc and therefore bind to a model. I think I need "real" server call/redirect otherwise it won't resolve the models